# Medal of Honor: Allied Assault patch 1.11 not working

Tags: technical-issues, medal-of-honor-allied-assault

I have installed Medal of Honor Allied Assault and its working fine. Then I installed patch 1.11, now whenever I start a mission everything freezes. The menu and everything else works fine, the loading completes but after that everything freezes. Whenever I press Esc within a mission, the menu shows up and the game unfreezes, I can see the mission's world and move the aim around, but when I close the menu, everything freezes again.

Anyone know what might be wrong?

I have Acer Aspire 5740. Core i3, 4 GB RAM, Windows 7 SP1, Intel Graphics Media Accelerator HD, with latest driver.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your have latest drivers and DirectX installed
and if that doesn't help try playing around with the graphic settings
if that doesn't work you can try reinstalling the entire game.

if everything fails look for the patch notes readme file and what are the changes that have been made in this patch maybe you don't need them and you should give up the patch.

Comment: Funny thing. It started to work with older version of graphic driver.